# Endless HTTP progressive streaming

Tags: video, mp4

I'm trying to create endless HTTP progressive video file streaming.

Task is to dynamically add encoded video data to file and playback this file in browser.

So far I've tried just to play in such way a static video file.

I'm not sure is it's possible to make such trick with a video file at all. I'm using mp4 h264 file. And it's moov atom has a duration preference.

Is it possible at all to make an mp4 file with can be played forever?